# Django add new entry from admin panel

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add a new entry by using the admin panel in Django
The problem is that I've already populated my DB with 200 records and if I try to add a new entry from admin I get a duplicated key error msg that keep increasing whenever I try the process again
error:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "app_entry_pkey"
```

admin.py:

```
admin.site.register(Entry)
```

model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: There's not really enough info here to diagnose the problem. If the admin works fine if you don't pre-populate the DB with 200 records, then it may be related to the way in which you're doing that.

Comment: it seems db table issue.. can you please check data.. also paste the model here

Comment: Well if I try to create a new entry from admin with no data in DB it works correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created the database table using Django, then most likely your auto_increment value was not updated when you imported the data outside of Django.

It may also be that when you imported the data you did not give the 200 records each their own unique primary key. I think that (some versions of) SQLite will sometimes allow that in mass imports.

## MySQL

For example, I’m looking at a MySQL table in Sequel Pro and see that it has an “auto_increment” value of 144. This means that the next primary key value will be 144.

You can see this value for your table (in MySQL) using:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM databaseName where name="entry"
```

Replacing “databaseName” with the name of your Django database. Other database software will likely have different syntax.

You can set the next auto_increment value (in MySQL) using:

```
ALTER TABLE databaseName.entry AUTO_INCREMENT ###
```

Again replacing databaseName with the name of your database; and as before, the syntax may vary depending on the database software you’re using.

If this doesn’t help, you may find it useful to show the table’s status and copy that into your question. This might also be useful in tracking down the issue:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE databaseName.entry
```

## Postgres

In Postgres, you can get the current value of the auto increment variable (called sequences in Postgres) using something like:

```
SELECT last_value FROM app_entry_pkey;
```

And you will likely set it to a new value with something like:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE app_entry_pkey RESTART WITH ###
```

or

```
SELECT setval('app_entry_pkey', ###)
```

Note, though, that I do not have a Postgres database handy to test these on. You may also find the following commands useful:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM entry
SELECT nextval('app_entry_pkey')
```

The latter should generally be larger than the former, and note that “id” is the name of the column in your “entry” model’s table; it may be different in your table. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-sequence.html for more information.

Comment: I forgot to say that my DB is postgresql

Comment: Yes, I should have guessed that from the constraint title. In your case, then, auto_increment values are part of “sequences”.

Comment: Ok I'm going to try that I will come back with an answer later